# can't provide a link for google play protect appeal

Tags: google-play-protect

each time I try to provide a link to my app, I receive an email saying "the link you have provided does not lead to an APK file or the file is corrupted". my apk file doesn't have a problem, I even tried some of the ways like using dropbox and changing the 0 at the end to 1 and shorten the link, and that didn't work eighter.

Comment: I'm fighting with the same issue, did you solve this in any way?

Comment: I tried again with dropbox after 8 months and it worked. I didn't receive an error email and after a day or two, my app was good to go.

Comment: I tried about a month ago and also didn't receive the rejection email, and the application got whitelisted a few days after :)